# ASP web forms ASCX User control for loop in repeater

Tags: asp.net, for-loop, syntax, webforms, user-controls

I have a repeater with a model that has status for each month.

So I want to use a for loop inside a repeater, but the problem is that one the variable is not accessible

Code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<% for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
  { %>
   <div class="DS_monthCol <%= GetStatusClassName(Item, month) %>">
      <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
  </div>

<% } %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The method `GetStatusClassName` is accessible - no problems. But is this case: `The name Item does not exits in the current context`, that is the error from Visual Studio.

If I use it like:

`<%# GetStatusClassName(Item, month) %>`

`The name month does not exits in the current context`

How to get both to be accessible ?

The idea is to avoid that:

```html
<div class='DS_monthCol <%# GetStatusClassName(Item, 1) %>'>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
<div class='DS_monthCol <%# GetStatusClassName(Item, 2) %>'>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
<div class='DS_monthCol <%# GetStatusClassName(Item, 3) %>'>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
<div class='DS_monthCol <%# GetStatusClassName(Item, 4) %>'>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
<div class='DS_monthCol <%# GetStatusClassName(Item, 5) %>'>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
<div class='DS_monthCol <%# GetStatusClassName(Item, 6) %>'>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
<div class='DS_monthCol <%# GetStatusClassName(Item, 7) %>'>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink7" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
<div class='DS_monthCol <%# GetStatusClassName(Item, 8) %>'>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink8" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
<div class='DS_monthCol <%# GetStatusClassName(Item, 9) %>'>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink9" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
<div class='DS_monthCol <%# GetStatusClassName(Item, 10) %>'>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink10" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
<div class='DS_monthCol <%# GetStatusClassName(Item, 11) %>'>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink11" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
<div class='DS_monthCol <%# GetStatusClassName(Item, 12) %>'>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink12" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ItemDataBound event

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>



string GetStatusClassName(Object obj, int month)
        {
            //your existing function
        }
```

Use ItemDataBound event as:

```
protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {

                //find place holder and add links in this place holder
                PlaceHolder ph = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("ph");

                //get your object of datasource assigned to repeater 
                Object dataItem = e.Item.DataItem;//need to add you items source

                for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
                {
                    //create div as per your example else you can directly add links to panel and handled display with css             
                    HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

                    // set id, class to whatever you want
                    div.Attributes.Add("class", "DS_monthCol " + GetStatusClassName(dataItem, month));

                    // declare a textbox
                    HyperLink lnk = new HyperLink();

                    //add link in PlaceHolder           
                    div.Controls.Add(lnk);

                    ph.Controls.Add(div);
                }


            }
        }
```

> Note: This code is not tested with data.

Comment: thanks but this will be a little bit complex, I do not know if it's possible to use inside data bound expression syntax `<%#  %>` local variables declared in `<%  %>` and without server side logic